# How do I get the relative path based on two absolute paths?

Tags: terminal, directory, path, symlink, relative-path

I need the relative path pointing to a certain directory.
I have this:

`/a/b/ef`
`/a/b/g/h/i/`

Now I want to create a relative symbolic link from the second folder to the first one, so it should look like this: `../../../ef`

How do I extract the relative path based on two absolute paths in Terminal?

I’m on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using Python and [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/302594-another-relative-filepath-script/).

1. Download and save the above as `relpath.py`, stop at `--- 8< --- snip --- 8< --- snip --- 8< --- snip --- 8< ---`
2. `cd` into the directory
3. Run `python relpath.py install` in Terminal
4. Then you can use the module from above

Here is my script, which uses the above module to create relative symlinks based on two directories: [relsymlink.py Gist](https://gist.github.com/Powder/7042961)